# Magento 2, email validation problem with new TLD (.shop)

Tags: magento2, validation, zend-framework

I have a .shop domain and adding email address in the backend (user info) i get the following errors:

- ... is not a valid hostname for email address
- ... appears to be a DNS hostname but cannot match TLD against known list
- ... appears to be a local network name but local network names are not allowed

exactly the same issue as described here: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4547

Is there a way to turn-off the email validation in magento 2.1?

Answer (score 1):

open SSH and run the command find . -name Hostname.php inside the root directory

you will get 4 location of files

```
./vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Validate/Hostname.php
./vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Controller/Router/Route/Hostname.php
./vendor/zendframework/zend-validator/src/Hostname.php
./vendor/zendframework/zend-mvc/src/Router/Http/Hostname.php
```

Open the file at this location 
`./vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Validate/Hostname.php`

and add your desired new tld as per the below image.

[image]

Once you edit the file you can check other 3 files also get the code updated in them. now you can save the new tlds.

Comment: works perfectly thanks. Just to clarify,  you need to check all the hostname.php files; there should be half that has the domain content and the does not. Just add the domain you need and it should work.